# how to Compare two tables and retrieve matched and unmatched data in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two table with different  column name and most of the values are same . I want the matched and unmatched data from the other table.

```
***
src-table
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
eid  | ename      | email                   |  country
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1     as           as@gmail.com                 india
 2     bs           bs@gmail.com                 usa
 3     cs           cs@gmail.com                 usa
 4     ds           ds@gmail.com                 india
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
tgt_table
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
eid  | ename      | email                   |  country
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1     as           as@gmail.com                 india
 2     bs           b@gmail.com                 india
 3     cs           cs@gmail.com                 usa
 4     ds           d@gmail.com                 india
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
expected output  for matched_data 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
src_coloumnname | src_data           | tgt_colomnname    | tgt_data
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
eid                  1                   eid                  1
eid                  2                   eid                  2
eid                  3                   eid                  3
eid                  4                   eid                  4
ename                as                  ename                as 
ename                bs                  ename                bs
ename                cs                  ename                cs
ename                ds                  ename                ds
email            as@gmail.com            email             as@gmail.com
email            cs@gmail.com            email             cs@gmail.com
country          india                   country            india
country          usa                     country            usa
country          india                   country            india
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
***
```

- similarly unmatched records
  how can i achieve that? can some one plz help me?

Comment: 'I have two table with different column name ' - they look the same to me?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to compare columns in a non relational way.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the SQL you already have and show us where/how it fails?

Comment: What are the fields that will link both tables and will always match? Only `eid`? What are the fields that can differ?

Comment: i need query for expected output? if you know plz share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done using one column at a time:

```
SELECT 'eid' AS match_column, l.eid AS src_value, r.eid AS tgt_value, CASE WHEN l.eid = r.eid THEN 'match' ELSE 'no match' END AS result
FROM table1 AS l
INNER JOIN table2 AS r ON l.eid = r.eid

UNION ALL

SELECT 'ename', l.ename, r.ename, CASE WHEN l.ename = r.ename THEN 'match' ELSE 'no match' END
FROM table1 AS l
INNER JOIN table2 AS r ON l.eid = r.eid

UNION ALL

SELECT 'email', l.email, r.email, CASE WHEN l.email = r.email THEN 'match' ELSE 'no match' END
FROM table1 AS l
INNER JOIN table2 AS r ON l.eid = r.eid

UNION ALL

SELECT 'country', l.country, r.country, CASE WHEN l.country = r.country THEN 'match' ELSE 'no match' END
FROM table1 AS l
INNER JOIN table2 AS r ON l.eid = r.eid
```

It matches columns where the rows match. It does not check rows that are missing from either table.

Comment: sir, is it possible in generic way  can you explain how is that possible? plz

Comment: Like you don't want to hard code column names... sorry, I have no idea.

Comment: sir i want only matched data i don't want unmatched date how can i achieve that ? when i remove unmatch in query i get null in that place could you pllease help me?

Comment: The CASE is there to "display" the result. If you want to limit results to matched rows only then remove all CASE and add the condition such as `WHERE l.ename = r.ename` to each query. If you want to consider NULL = NULL then use `WHERE l.ename <=> r.ename` instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can do a simple join, i think you can do this

```
SELECT * FROM T1 FULL OUTER JOIN T2 ON TRUE
```

or
    SELECT * FROM T1 , T2

for everyting

SELECT * FROM T1 FULL OUTER JOIN T2 ON T1.C1 <> T2.T1_C1
for the unmatched

SELECT * FROM T1 FULL OUTER JOIN T2 ON T1.C1 = T2.T1_C1
for matched

you can also change type of join for matching
here the join documentation
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp
you can also

```
SELECT T1.C1, T2.C1,T1.C2, ..., CASE WHEN T1.C1=T2.T1_C1 THEN 'MATCH' ELSE 'NOT MATCH' END FROM T1,T2
```

for have you result with the evidence of matching
this is the documenation of case
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp